# What does い adjective くform + noun signify?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

The title of [this](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011444081000/k10011444081000.html) news article is

> 将棋の[藤井]{ふじい}[聡太]{そうた}さん　今まででいちばん若く「[七段]{しちだん}」になる

Why is 若く used here instead of 若い? As far as I know, い adjectives change into く form when they come before verbs but 「七段」に なる doesn't seem like a verb here. What does this kind of grammatical usage of い adjective signify ? Examples would be nice.

Thank you :)

Comment: なる is a verb, and 七段になる is a verb phrase.

Comment: **早く**家に帰ってくれ！　**ちゃんと**僕の話を聞いてください！などの話もいいじゃないでしょうか

Answer (score 4):

As Sjiveru says, it's an adverb modifying a verb phrase. Saying that い-adjectives change to く form before a verb is an oversimplification; く form is the adverbial form.

This a tricky sentence because we would use an adjective in English, so let's look at another example.

> I ran quickly to the store.

As you can see, "quickly" is an adverb modifying "ran." Now, in Japanese:

> 速く店まで走った。

The word order here is perhaps a bit awkward, but you can see that 速く isn't modifying 店, it's modifying 走った. If you changed it to:

> 速い店まで走った。

It wouldn't make any sense. What's a fast store?

Now, to the original headline:

> 将棋の藤井聡太さん　今まででいちばん若く「七段」になる

Fujii-san is the youngest Shōgi player to attain 7th level. Or in headline-speak "Shōgi's Fujii Souta-san youngest to attain 7th level"

If you changed 若く to an adjective, it would mean that Fujii-san is "becoming the youngest 7th-level." This is awkward if not ungrammatical, because unlike, say, "black-belt," "7th-level" is somewhat unnatural as a metonymy for "7th-level player".

Note: I know nothing about Shōgi, so I'm not sure if "7th-level" is a natural translation or if we'd say "7-dan" or something else in English!

Comment: Also, it's pretty cool that the previous record holder was named 一二三。

Comment: This is not a sentence; It is a headline.  People here call everything a "sentence".  A real sentence in a news article would surely contain the subject/topic marker instead of a space and a 「なった/なりました」 instead of 「なる」 at the end.

Comment: Fair enough; I'll edit.

Comment: It happens to be correct even if it was 一番若い７段, and it's not awkward at all. If you feel awkward, the problem is translating 7 dan into 7th level. In English speaking shogi society, ７段 is called 7th-dan.

Comment: @user4092 Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to say 店まで速く走った? Which one is more natural? "速く店まで走った。" , "店まで速く走った。", or it depends on the context.

Comment: The latter sounds slightly better to me, but I'm not a native speaker. They're definitely both grammatical.